# Why should I only use BizTalk to process HL7 Messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Why we need to use BizTalk to process HL7 Messages? Is there any other alternative rather than BizTalk?

I need exact reason  why we need to opt out for BizTalk only...Is there anyother way to Process HL7 Messages?

Answer (score 6):

Q: 'How many ways are there to skin a cat?' A: 'Lots'

There are lots of ways to implement HL7 messaging, which at the end of the day is just a messaging standard (see http://www.hl7.org/ or http://www.hl7.org.uk/). Oracle's WebLogic product has a HL7 adapter, IBM's WebSphere product has a HL7 adapter, iWay has a HL7 adapter etc. etc. etc. or you could 'roll your own' using your favourite language.

Companies usually go with an integration product (BizTalk, WebLogic, Websphere etc.) rather than rolling their own given that these products usually have done the hard-work of implementing HL7 (add whatever other message standard you want here), allowing you to *easily* interface with that message standard. You also benefit from the additional features of the integration product (in the case of BizTalk, this is redundant messaging, mapping, a WIDE variety of transport adapters, Orchestration, message validation, enterprise grade load-balancing etc.)

Alternatively, you could 'roll your own' for the particular messages you are concerned with in the language of your choice AND then add any of the enterprisey features you need, however this will be a much bigger undertaking that buying an off-the-shelf middleware product that already implements the standard and is likely to be dearer once you have factored in Project Management, Testing etc.

At the end of the day, it comes down to which technology platform you use within your business - are you a Java / .Net / or Other shop? Once you clearly have that defined, look for the middleware product that suits your platform knowledge and evaluate, or 'roll your own'.